# Hardware component at fault of BSOD, need help in identifying it

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard, bsod, crash

Hey to whoever is reading!

I am facing issues with my PC, it goes BSOD with an ***"IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL"*** from time to times.

This happens out of the blue, while idle or playing games, or simply letting pc just '*vibe*' in the background.

Sometimes it goes BSOD and during mid DUMP file creation completely shuts down, then restarts to UEFI where it shows that there's no Memory hooked to the PC. After restarting the pc it goes back to normal.

I suspect it's a hardware related issue, but not sure which component could be responsible. Maybe you guys have an insight.

**Now things I have tested:**

**Windows Memory Diagnostic Tool**: No problems have been detected with RAM

**Reset Windows**: didn't help (drivers not at fault).

**Cinebench**: stress tested CPU (single-core/multi-core), no crashes.

**BurnInTest**: set everything to max for 15 mins, 0 crashes or errors.

Yes I have reseted my Windows 10 to factory state. I still had the issue so I swapped to Win11 and still the issue persists

So I suppose this could be PSU or Motherboard related?? Any ideas? Opinions what it could be?

Comment: *Windows Memory Diagnostic Tool* is not very effective at detecting RAM problems. Instead, try running "memtest86+" overnight for 8 hours or so. If it passes the test, then I'd say it's either the motherboard or the PSU.

Answer (score 0):

Have you (or an application) [changed interrupt request (IRQ) settings](https://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/manage-irq-settings-windows/), or are you overclocking the CPU or GPU? Check the IRQ's are set to OEM specs, which vary by machine model.

A simple test if it's hardware or OS/software: boot and run for a while from an external drive, such as [Ubuntu Live USB](https://itsfoss.com/create-live-usb-of-ubuntu-in-windows/). If Ubuntu runs for a day or two and never crashes, then you know the issue is either with the Windows installation (even though you updated to v. 11) or possibly with the HDD/SSD.